# cc: error: cannot open message catalog: ecc.cat

Tags: c, unix, hp-ux

I have a test script which is internally calling make to compile a sample C programme. 
But for some unknown reasons, the compilation is not going through. It is throwing below error:

```
08-27 20:23:45.777 make program         cc -o /mnt2/pfst.4183/bin/program program.c
cc: error: cannot open message catalog: ecc.cat
cc: error 1901: unknown message
*** Error exit code 1

Stop.
Ret = 1
```

When I tried to compile the same program on command prompt, it is going through successfully.

The same script is working absolutely fine in other machine.

Can anyone please suggest what this error is all about?

PFB is some more details:

```
$>/opt/aCC/lib/nls/msg/C # ls -lrt
total 512
-r--r--r--   1 bin        bin         121889 Nov 18  2006 ecc.cat
-r--r--r--   1 bin        bin         136836 Nov 18  2006 ecc.msgs
$>/opt/aCC/lib/nls/msg/C #

$>/opt/aCC/lib/nls/msg/C # /opt/cifsutil/bin/stat /opt/aCC/lib/nls/msg/C/ecc.cat
FILE: /opt/aCC/lib/nls/msg/C/ecc.cat
st_dev      = 0x40000003 -> major/minor: 64/3
st_ino      = 14209
st_fstype   = 9
st_mode     = 0x8124 ---> S_IFREG=1  S_IFBLK=0  S_IFCHR=0  S_IFDIR=0  S_IFIFO=0
                          S_ISUID=0  S_ISGID=0  STICKY=0   mode_bits=r--r--r--

st_basemode = 0x0124 ---> S_IFREG=0  S_IFBLK=0  S_IFCHR=0  S_IFDIR=0  S_IFIFO=0
                          S_ISUID=0  S_ISGID=0  STICKY=0   mode_bits=r--r--r--
st_uid      = 2
st_gid      = 2
st_atime    = 0x5040623e, 1346396734  [Fri Aug 31 12:35:34 2012]
st_mtime    = 0x455e1bb4, 1163795380  [Sat Nov 18 01:59:40 2006]
st_ctime    = 0x503f65ce, 1346332110  [Thu Aug 30 18:38:30 2012]
st_size     = 121889 bytes
st_blocks   = 120         st_blksize = 8192 bytes
st_nlink    = 1           st_acl     = 0
st_remote   = 0           st_rcnode  = 0x0001
st_netdev   = 0x00000000  st_cnode   = 0x0001
st_netino   = 0           st_netsite = 0x0000
st_realdev  = 0x40000003
st_rdev     = <n/a>

$>/opt/aCC/lib/nls/msg/C #
$>/opt/aCC/lib/nls/msg/C # /usr/bin/file /opt/aCC/lib/nls/msg/C/ecc.cat
/opt/aCC/lib/nls/msg/C/ecc.cat: NLS message catalog, 1898 messages
$>/opt/aCC/lib/nls/msg/C #
```

Answer (score 0):

ecc.cat is the error message catalog for the ecom compiler (`cc` runs `ecom` on an Itanium system). The compiler looks for it in `/opt/aCC/lib/nls/msg/$LANG/ecc.cat`.

Can you try setting `LANG` to `C` in your script? `/opt/aCC/lib/nls/msg/C/ecc.cat` should exist.

Alternatively you could look in `/opt/aCC/lib/nls/msg` and pick a language in there, such as `en_US`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your clarification. But it is not going through even after setting LANG to C in the script. Is there any other options which I can try out ?

Comment: Does `/opt/aCC/lib/nls/msg` exist? If so, what directories do you see in there?

Comment: Yes, it exist and has only one directory- C. And it contains two files- ecc.cat and ecc.msgs

Comment: Can you paste the output from these commands: `stat /opt/aCC/lib/nls/msg/C/ecc.cat` and `file /opt/aCC/lib/nls/msg/C/ecc.cat`

Comment: I have edited the original query with these details. Please refer them